# Symfony2 + YML: import files without breaking indent

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, yaml, foselasticabundle

I got a small question:
I'm currently building a Symfony app coupled with an ElasticSearch index. I use FOS_Elastica, and came across some snag. Not quite a problem, but just a question of ergonomics.

For the purpose of my app, I have some pretty large entities, and I have at least 10 of these. Writing the YML mapping for all these entities is not only tedious, it also makes a stupidly long YML config file. Do not say I don't have to write the mapping for each entity, I know I don't, but it's mandatory here at my work.

So here's the real question:
I'd like to separate each mapping in a file of its own for clarity purpose, and import these several files under the `fos_elastica: > indexes: > app: > types: > entity:` indentation.
Is it possible somehow? the `import:` key seems to work only at the root indent of the file. Or maybe I'm doing it wrong.

Thanks to all!